# How to limit the number of tasks to the first arguments in GNU Parallel?

Tags: gnu-parallel

I want to run a series of parallel jobs based on a set of arguments while assigning a second argument. I use the `--link` option in `GNU Parallel` as

```
parallel --jobs 3 --link echo ::: A B C ::: D E F G
A D
B E
C F
A G
```

It perfectly works when the number of the first set of arguments is higher than the second set.

In the above example, task `A` has been repeated twice.

How can I avoid any repetition in the first set of arguments? In other words, the tasks are `A..C` and `D..G` are just periodic arguments for the `A..C` tasks.

The argument should be

```
A D
B E
C F
```

like the case when the number of the first set is higher,

```
parallel --jobs 3 --link echo ::: A B C H ::: D E F
A D
B E
C F
H D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want an input source to repeat, make the input sources the same length. Instead of:

```
parallel --jobs 3 --link echo ::: A B C ::: D E F G
```

run:

```
parallel --jobs 3 --link echo ::: A B C ::: D E F
```

Currently you can also:

```
parallel --jobs 3 echo ::: A B C :::+ D E F G
```

but this is considered a bug, so no not expect this to work in the future.

Comment: I cannot control the length of the arguments, as it is not a fixed script (it should work for various arguments). Why is it a bug, to be fixed? `:::+` is a handy option, why removing it?

Comment: @Googlebot The syntax will stay the same, but it will have the same behaviour as `--link`.

Comment: why removing a useful feature and having two different syntaxes for a single existing feature? `--link` is already a well-defined feature.